# Laravel join and paginate using query builder without duplicated rows

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, query-builder

I can't make a join & paginate between two tables using query builder,  without receiving duplicated data.

Example:

```
DB::table('users')->distinct()
 ->leftJoin('pictures','users.id','=','pictures.user_id')
 ->select('users.*', 'pictures.src')
 ->paginate();
```

- A user has many pictures.
- This is bringing as many users as pictures it have.
- Using Mysql 5.7.
- I've tried using distinct('users.id') after and before the select...

The other thing that I've tried is to make an iteration after the paginate, query the pictures of every user and append them, but I couldn't access the protected array items inside the paginated collection.

Comment: Your query is working as expected.  What output do you want here?

Comment: If single `user` has `multiple` pictures, which `pictures.src` do you want to return in your query? Let's say that, if user has pictures [A,B,C,D], you always want to return A?

Comment: use eager loading you will receive an array of pictures with every user

Comment: I want to receive users and everyone of them with an array of pictures, not duplicated users for every picture they have related